# Where do I put environment variables that I want set on boot (or login)?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Where do I put environment variables that I want set on boot (or login)?

In particular, I want to set JAVA_HOME and add %JAVA_HOME%/bin to the path.

Answer (score 2):

To add, remove or edit Environment variables in Windows 7 follow these simple steps:

1. Right click on the Computer icon on your Desktop and choose Properties option.
2. In the System window click on Advanced system settings in the left pane as highlighted below
3. In the System Properties window select Advanced tab and click on Environment Variables… button given at the bottom of the window as highlighted below
4. In the Environment Variables window you will notice two columns User variables for a username and System variables.

You put them in User Variables if you want them to be set during login, and in System Variables if you want them to be available for all Users.